# Apache web server 32bit on 64bit computer

Tags: python, django, apache, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

simple question - if I run apache 32bit version, on 64bit OS, with a lot of memory (32GB RAM). Does this mean all the memory will go to waste since 32bit apache can't use more then 3GB ram?

Answer (score 0):

I would assume so. You should definitely go for a 64-bit version of Apache to make use of all the memory available.

Comment: The problem is the python libraries compability. Which might be fine and maybe not (I dont use numpy or similar but still). Isnt the memory usage is also depend on the OS ? Or number of apache processes?

Comment: It also depends on the load of the apache web server. If the load is not too heavy the roughly 4GB of RAM will probably be enough to run your web site smoothly. I assume (sorry I have no detailed knowledge of this) that Python stuff will run in 1 or more process(es) which means that each of them can consume up to those roughly 4GB of RAM. So you might not make full usage of the resources of your server, but if you are concerned about the compatibility of the libraries a 32-bit Apache https might be the safer way to go. Otherwise, you'll have to try it out and test everything :-)